# OR condtion in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Hi I want to use OR Condition in smarty please help me

```
{if $productgroup.gid neq '69' or
    $productgroup.gid neq '68'  or
    $productgroup.gid neq '27' or
    $productgroup.gid neq '31' or
    $productgroup.gid neq '70' or
    $productgroup.gid neq '71'}

    <select name="name" id="name" onchange="plan()">
        <option value="1">Car</option>
    </select>

{/if}
```

Comment: What do you wish to achieve here?

Comment: `neq`? What should that be?

Comment: What is happening on you code now?

Comment: neq means not equal to operator

Comment: Have you tried it without quotation between number?

Comment: Let me know what happened if there's no quotation around the numbers

Comment: thanks Kimbarcelona it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no quotation between numeric during the if condition:

```
{if $productgroup.gid neq 69 or
    $productgroup.gid neq 68  or
    $productgroup.gid neq 27 or
    $productgroup.gid neq 31 or
    $productgroup.gid neq 70 or
    $productgroup.gid neq 71}

    <select name="name" id="name" onchange="plan()">
        <option value="1">Car</option>
    </select>

{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using OR, you can use in_array, which is shorter and easier to maintain:

```
{ if !in_array($productgroup.gid, array(69,68,27,31,70,71)) }
    <select name="name" id="name" onchange="plan()">
        <option value="1">Car</option>
    </select>
{/if}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code will always result in TRUE because a number is always not equal to either 69 or 68.
If you are trying to check if the "gid" is no 27, 31, 68, 69, 70 or 71 then that needs to happen in a different way (in addition to the other answer about strings and numbers):

```
{if ! ( $productgroup.gid eq 69 or
        $productgroup.gid eq 68 or
        $productgroup.gid eq 27 or
        $productgroup.gid eq 31 or
        $productgroup.gid eq 70 or
        $productgroup.gid eq 71 ) }

    <select name="name" id="name" onchange="plan()">
        <option value="1">Car</option>
    </select>

{/if}
```

Comment: Hmm.. i think what is wrong is Smarty reads the condition as string whereas the value being compared is interger that's why it's always false. If you make it that way, it will always be true

Comment: Incorrect. {IF not (x == 2 or x == 3)} will first evaluate the stuff in inner parentheses, resulting in TRUE if x is either 2 or 3. Now if you reverse that with "not" it will result TRUE for all numbers that are not 2 or 3.

Comment: You reversed the condition. I've overlooked